# How to change video playbackRate with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, video, coffeescript

I have a video, and I need it to run slower.
Current code:

```
ready = undefined
set_rate = undefined

set_rate = =>
  $('#background').attr playbackRate: '.1'
  return

ready = =>
  set_rate()
  return

$(document).ready ready
```

`$('#background')` selects my `<video>`

I have also tried `$('#background').playbackRate = .1` and `$('#background').playbackRate = '.1'`
But I can never see any difference(alerting the playbackRate results in .1), I've also tried using vlc to slow down the video, but it becomes jumpy, and un-usable.
Notice: I am using coffeescript, not javascript (even though they're 'the same')
Also, the video is muted, I believe that makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `attr()` method ([see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)) expects a string which is the name of the attribute you want to change, and the value you want to set it to.

```
$('#background').attr 'playbackRate', 0.1
```

---

## EDIT

If that doesn't work, try setting it directly via the DOM element rather than jQuery (use `[0]` to access it from it's jQuery wrapper)

```
 $('#background')[0].playbackRate = 3.0;
```

If it's still not working, please post an example snippet of you code here or in a jsfiddle where we can reproduce and try out fixes.

Comment: I'm aware, the playbackRate is being successfully set that way, but there's no change